# Problema al buscar recursivamente en c#

Tags: c#

tengo una aplicacion en la cual necesito buscar recursivamente todos los archivos con extension .pst y .ost.

Me funciona de forma recursiva si selecciono una ruta que especifica, pero necesito que busque en todo el disco C:. En ese caso, no me funciona si quiero que sea en todo el disco.

Os pongo el codigo del boton que hace esa funcion que necesito, por si me lo podeis corregir.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //DirectoryInfo dirPrograms = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");

            var dirs = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\prueba", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".pst") || s.EndsWith(".ost"));

            try
            {

                foreach (var di in dirs)
                {
                    checkedListBox.Items.Add(di);
                }

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {

            }
        }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando dices "*no me funciona*" ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que observas y qué comportamiento esperabas?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster 
Me refiero a que si busco los archivos en la ubicacion "c:\pruebas", me lista todos los archivos recursivamente en esa ubicacion sin ninun problema.

En cambio, si le cambio la ruta para que haga un busqueda recursiva por todo el disco (C:\), no me devuelve ningún valor en el listbox.
Me lleva directamente al "catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)" y no se como omitir los archivos bloqueados.

Comment: Haz el try/catch dentro del foreach, ¿no? Te saltará la excepción pero la ignoras. También igual en el API hay un método que te compruebe los permisos sin que lance la excepción, pero esto es más sencillo (aunque igual menos eficiente).

Answer (score 1):

<s>La función de búsqueda que utilizas no aplica recursividad.</s>
La recursividad que se aplica especificando la opción `SearchOption.AllDirectories` tiene dos inconvenientes: si ocurre una excepción no la puedes tratar de forma granular (o todo va bien o todo va mal) y, mientras está enumerando los directorios no tienes un *feedback* de qué está haciendo.

Hay varias formas de hacer la búsqueda recursiva optimizada, pero te pongo un ejemplo sencillo que espero que te sirva de punto de partida.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Neurons
{
    public static class program
    {
        public static void SearchRecursive(string Dir, List<string> Found)
        {
            try
            {
                int CurCount = Found.Count;
                Console.Write($"Buscando en carpeta: {Dir}...");
                Found.AddRange(Directory
                    .EnumerateFiles(Dir)
                    .Where(fn => fn.ToUpper().EndsWith(".OST") || fn.ToUpper().EndsWith(".PST"))
                    );
                Console.WriteLine($" encontrados {Found.Count - CurCount}");

                foreach (var SubDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Dir))
                    SearchRecursive(SubDir, Found);
            }
            catch
            { }
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> Found = new List<string>();
            SearchRecursive(@"C:\", Found);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón, gracias, he corregido la respuesta.